# Jelastic Glassfish Connection Pool - Context

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, glassfish, connection-pooling

my problem happens only on Jelastic cloud server nodes, not on local machine.

I have done these:

- I have uploaded mysql jar driver to the `lib` folder of glassfish
- I have created my connection pool and the ping is successfull
- I created data source

but when I run the following JSP:

```
<%@page import="java.io.Writer"%>
<%@page import="javax.sql.DataSource"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.Context"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <%
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/rook-server");
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
root cause

javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
root cause

com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
root cause

com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
root cause

com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
root cause

javax.resource.ResourceException: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1
```

Comment: I had the same problem with my jelastic trial account. Somehow they/I got it working some days later. Don't know what was the reason, most likely a server configuration problem - something that the user cannot control. The jelastic support forum has some threads on this topic as well. Maybe you will get more help if you try to ask your question there (although sometimes there is a jelastic support team member around here on SO).

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Jelastic team. We are analyzing this problem now. We'll let you know when we find the reason of it. Try to restart GlassFish, maybe this will help.
Regards,
Marina

Comment: What is the result of analyzing?